# Find the highest number in SQL database, if unavailable return '0'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Currently I am working on producing a way for ASP.NET C# web app to retrieve the highest number in a column in SQL database. Right now, I manage to produce the following line of code.

```
commTagNo = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(ComponentTagEntry) FROM dbo.HullDataSheet", connHull);

connHull.Open();
int newTagNo = (int)commTagNo.ExecuteScalar();
connHull.Close();

newTagNo = newTagNo + 1;
```

where `connHull` is the `SqlConnection` for above line of codes.

The above code can retrieve the highest number in column `ComponentTagEntry` if and only if the database already have a minimum one row of data.

If the database is empty, it will return 'Specified cast is invalid' since there are no data to do `.ExecuteScalar()`.

What I need is, when the database is empty, for the code to retrieve the highest number as '0'.

I know that I have to modify the above code with if then statement but I don't know the value that I must compare to the true/false statement.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Might i suggest that you use an Identity column for the 'Tag Numbers' instead of this logic? Its possible if there are multiple concurrent users that a duplicate id could be generated (race condition)

Comment: 'ComponentTagEntry' is my Identity column in the table where Identity increment is 1 and Identity seed is 1. In this project, the database wilI have to show in table form. so I can't change the Identity seed to 0.

Comment: Not sure if it's recommendable or not, but does it work if you use a nullable int `int?`?

Comment: So you are using 'newTagNo' as a hint/show only? cause its even more likely to be invalid if its shown to the user as the next possible id in a table. But as long as you don't attempt to insert it the data will be ok at least :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is the way to go:

```
select coalesce(max(ComponentTagEntry)) from ...
```

For example:

```
create table dbo.HullDataSheet (ComponentTagEntry int);

select coalesce(max(ComponentTagEntry), 0) from HullDataSheet

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

-----------
0

(1 row(s) affected)

Table 'HullDataSheet'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Comment: If there are no rows, `coalesce` doesn't do anything. It doesn't create a row.

Answer (score 1):

ISNULL operator should help.

```
commTagNo = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ComponentTagEntry), 0) FROM dbo.HullDataSheet", connHull);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
int newTagNo = 0;
object testMe = commTagNo.ExecuteScalar();
if (testMe != null) { newTagNo = (int)testMe; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Compatible in both SQL Server & Mysql:

```
select 
    case 
       when MAX(ComponentTagEntry) IS NULL 
          then 0 
          else MAX(ComponentTagEntry) 
    end 
from 
    dbo.HullDataSheet
```